# Running through appended data frame to locate where the first positive number is in python

Tags: python, list, pandas, append

I have a appended series using pandas. I will call it S. Each S[i], for some i, has 50 data points. I will call these j.

I want to go through each i, and for instance for j=1, find where the first positive s[i][1] occurs and record what the number is. The output I am looking for is hence a i by 2 dataframe where [i,1] records the j's for each i and [i,2] records what the positive number was.

Preferably, I would like a vectorized version for instance like sapply/apply in R.

I hope the description made sense.. I hope there is someone out there who could help me with this!

The following is an example with i=4 and j=6.

```
S[0]:
2013-01-02_59   -0.004739
2013-01-02_61   +0.002435
2013-01-02_74   -0.004772
2013-01-02_75   -0.004772
2013-01-02_77   -0.002452
2013-01-02_78   -0.009423

S[1]:
2013-01-02_60   -0.007048
2013-01-02_62   -0.002435
2013-01-02_75   +0.004772
2013-01-02_76   -0.002446
2013-01-02_78   +0.007114
2013-01-02_79   -0.004772

S[2]: 
2013-01-02_61   -0.004739
2013-01-02_63   +0.002435
2013-01-02_76   -0.002446
2013-01-02_77   -0.004772
2013-01-02_79   -0.002452
2013-01-02_80   +0.002446

S[3]: 
2013-01-02_62   -0.004739
2013-01-02_64   +0.002435
2013-01-02_77   -0.004772
2013-01-02_78   +0.009423
2013-01-02_80   -0.000121
2013-01-02_81   -0.004772
```

My desire output in this example is thus:

```
Output:
NA    NA
1     +0.002435
2     +0.004772
4     +0.009423
2     +0.007114
3     +0.002446
```

The first row of the output is NA because it was never positive.

Comment: Please post raw data, code and what your desired output looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below will identify `index` and `value` of first positive value per `series`, and insert `np.nan` in cases where there is no positive value. Some sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(10):
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.Series(data=np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 50), name=i)], axis=1)

df = df.transpose()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 50 columns):
0     10 non-null float64
1     10 non-null float64
2     10 non-null float64
3     10 non-null float64
4     10 non-null float64
5     10 non-null float64
....
45    10 non-null float64
46    10 non-null float64
47    10 non-null float64
48    10 non-null float64
49    10 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(50)
```

Use: 
    df.loc[3, :] = -1

```
tmp = df.apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame({'value': x[x > 0]}).reset_index().iloc[0] if not x[x > 0].empty else (x.index[-1], np.nan), axis=1)
```

to get pairs of `index`, `values` in the `columns` for each original `series` `i`, the latter referenced by the `index:

```
   index     value
0      1  0.608962
1      2  0.487893
2      1  0.850135
3     49       NaN
4      1  0.870091
5      2  0.469713
6      1  0.331851
7      0  0.036980
8      0  0.387298
9      3  0.723645
```

Comment: Thank you Stefan, this is exactly what I was looking for. It seems like I have to concat my data first. The data is pretty big, and due to non-uniform indexes, simple concat does not give an i by j data frame. Even with ignore_index=True, it does not seem to work.

Comment: I am doing pd.concat(S,axis=1, ignore_index = True)

Comment: If you see from my example, each series, S[0],...,S[3] all have different set of indexes and this is causing the problem. Can you teach me what I can do? Thank you for your time.

Comment: I see, this is a critical piece of information. I assume you need to keep the original indexes? Why are you combining them in the same `DataFrame` if the indexes are different?

Comment: More fundamentally, why are you combining the series into one `DataFrame` if the indexes are different? You would have to add and indicator variable to indicate the source series, group on the indicator and then run the `apply` from the answer, but then you could just as well do this for the series without combining them.

Comment: Indexes don't matter as much for this particular data set. Thanks Stefan. The reset_index() fixed all the problems. I am not sure if my code is the most efficient one but it works for now. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Stefan, I got another problem. From tmp = df.apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x[x > 0]).reset_index().iloc[0], axis=1), I get the following error "('index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0', u'occurred at index 0')". It is because there are times where non of them are positive, which is also my interest. When none of them are zero. I just want it to record the lest index (j) and some value, NA for value. Should I post a new question?